# How to use something like SUMIF with a formula criteria

Tags: google-sheets

This is for an online game and I am trying to build a database of what I have in the game. I have modified my data to protect my privacy a bit and bit in some better example data.

I essentially have a training courses log sheet, and a building database sheet with different fire stations. Each station has a set of staff working at them. Each one also requires a certain number of staff to operate the vehicles at that station. I also then can have people in training courses.

In the image below I have combined the two sheets onto one sheet just to make it easier to illustrate. To note, the end date would be used to exclude any completed courses from being used in the "In-Training" count.

[image]

And here is an annotated mock-up of what the results of the example above should automatically be turned into.

[image]

Comment: Sorry but I am confused by your images. Is `Training Sheet` column `D` (Station) supposed to hold `Stations Sheet` column `A`  (Name) **and** `Training Sheet` column `C` (Num of Staff) supposed to hold `Stations Sheet` column `B`  (In-Training). Also, what kind of data is in `Training Sheet` column `A` (Name)? People like John, Ann? So, `Station`=`Name` and `Num of Staff`=`In-Training`? Or...? Could you match your headers accordingly and give more realistic data?

Comment: @marikamitsos Yes it sounds like you have it right. Sorry my naming for this example was a bit confusing. But essentially the training log is just mentioning which station (Stations Sheet) is having what training, for how long, and how many people will be present. No names or anything are listed, the training log is just the number of people that will be present in that training. So then when I am on the stations sheet I would like to be able to SUM all of the currently active training associated with that station. I will try and adjust my images

Comment: @marikamitsos I have updated the OP and completely re-wrote it and gave new examples with annotations. Hopefully that makes it more clear.

Comment: Thank you for the updated info. Please check my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You mention

> ...on the stations sheet I would like to be able to SUM all of the currently active training associated with that station.

> ...the end date would be used to exclude any completed courses from being used in the "In-Training" count.

You do not clarify though -or I least it is unclear to me- whether you will have 1 or more than 1 active training courses in each station.
To cover both possibilities

**Case 1**
If there is **just 1 active** training course in each station.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A11,IF(B14:D>NOW(),{D14:D,B14:C},""),3,0),""))
```

The `VLOOKUP` function will only pick the first from top active course.

[image]

**Case 2**
If there is **1 or more active** training course in each station.

```
=ArrayFormula(IFERROR(VLOOKUP(A2:A11, 
                         QUERY(B14:D,"select D, sum(C)where B>now() group by D label sum(C) '' ",0) 
                                            ,2,0),""))
```

What we actually did here is replace the range `{D14:D,B14:C}` with the query formula. The `QUERY` function will pick all active courses.

[image]

---

*(Please adjust ranges to your needs)*

Functions used:

- [`QUERY`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093343)
- [`ArrayFormula`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093275)
- [`IFERROR`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093304)
- [`VLOOKUP`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/)
- [`IF`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093364)
- [`NOW`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092981)

Comment: Yeah sorry I wasn't clear, case 2 was the version I needed to use as there could be multiple training courses. I appreciate the effort! I knew this would be a bit complicated to do but didn't realize it would need so many different functions! I'll have to take a look at the functions you used like Query and ArrayFormula as I have not used those before. 

I got it working nicely with the training data on the separate sheet and it is all good. Again, thank you!